# simplify ngClass conditionals that uses ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ng-class

I have an array with 5 string values
excited, happy, neutral, sad, angry

I am using ngClass and ngFor as to simplify the html and so I don't have to repeat everything 5x for each value.

The problem is that the ngClass statement is very bulky and I can't find a proper way to simplify it. Is there any way to make this shorter?

```
<mat-icon *ngFor="let smiley of smileys" svgIcon="emote_{{smiley}}" 
                [ngClass]="{ happy: smiley === 'happy', sad:  smiley === 'sad', neutral:  smiley === 'neutral', angry:  smiley === 'angry', excited:  smiley === 'excited'}" (click)="selected(smiley, $event)"></mat-icon>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can if you define them in `.ts` file.

Comment: are your class names always equal to the `smiley` value?

Comment: @molamk they are, yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply write

`[ngClass]="smiley"`

Comment: Simple and efficient !

Comment: wow yes this indeed worked! I thought i had tried it before but I did {{smiley}} instead, which did not work. Thank you!

Comment: To be more clear, using "[ ]" in the template define that you use the variable name instead of value, so [ngClass]="smiley" equal to ngClass="{{smiley}}"

Comment: Very nice what is also possible is to add multiple smilies. By using `[ngClass]="[smiley1, smiley2]"` After this I also noticed it can be unlimted by making `smiley = ['happy', 'sad', 'neutral']` aka `smiley.push('happy')` and keep the `[ngClass]="smiley"`.

Answer (score 0):

make the smileys array content be smarter, encapsulate the concrete class inside the smiley and use it in assignment to the class resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Put this part into a function  happy: smiley === 'happy', sad:  smiley === 'sad', neutral:  smiley === 'neutral', angry:  smiley === 'angry', excited:  smiley === 'excited', maybe a switch or if clauses and return the css-class-name from there.

Then you could write:
`[ngClass]="determineHappiness()`

There is a question solving something similar: [check this one out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992193/using-ng-class-with-a-function-call-called-multiple-times)