# Get one-time binding to work for ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969926/angular-lazy-one-time-binding-for-expressions), but I can't get that solution working, so I'm wondering if there's something different in my specifics.

The code is really, really simple:

```
<h1 ng-if="vm.building.name !== undefined">update {{vm.building.name}}</h1>
```

As written, this snippet works fine. If `vm.building.name` is set, tag appears.

However, if I try to make the one-time binding work, that is:

```
<h1 ng-if="::vm.building.name !== undefined">update {{vm.building.name}}</h1>
```

The tag doesn't appear at all. I've tried variations:

```
<h1 ng-if="::(vm.building.name !== undefined)">update {{vm.building.name}}</h1>
```

Still nope. It's such a frustratingly simple thing. Hell, the code seems to work in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqn6jajz/), but I can't get it working for my particular app. Is there a setting somewhere? Some random bit of trivia I need to change?

Is there I'm using angular `1.5.7`, if that matters.

#### EDIT

```
<h1 ng-if="vm.building.name !== undefined">update {{::vm.building.name}}</h1>
```

That is, setting the `{{::vm.building.name}}` ultimately gives me the result I'm looking for, but at the cost of a additional, useless watcher, right?

Further edit on my edit: this isn't a great solution for a number of reasons.

#### EDIT 2

My problem stems from the fact that `vm.building.name` waits on an API call and therefore misses the first `$watch` digest (I think). So instead of "one-time" as defined by angular, is there a way to have `ng-if` do its thing directly after `vm.building.name` is set the first time and then quit?

Comment: Is `vm.building.name` set immediately or do you wait for a value? [Delaying setting the value](https://jsfiddle.net/zqkLbcxx/1/) produces what you describe.

Comment: Good catch. `vm.building.name` waits on an API call. That said, is there a fix?

Comment: Agreed. What _do_ I want?

Comment: @crowhill Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In here you're checking one-time data binding `vm.building.name` value with `undefined` and since it is one-time data binding this condition will always be false.

modify your `ng-if` and make it more simpler

```
<h1 ng-if="::vm.building.name">update {{::vm.building.name}}</h1>
```

Please find working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/QA6ZA7e0zHnN45oQWzQH?p=preview

This will work!

Cheers!