# Angular one time binding ng-if multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ng-if, one-time-binding

In my templates i've got a lot of conditions related to my user rights and products rights, for example:

```
<div ng-if="user.rights == 'admin'  || user.rights == 'owner'  || products.rights.technical"></div>
```

Thoses rights can't be changed without going to a new page... so I was thinking that I could use one-binding :: for better performance.

I tried:

```
<div ng-if="::(user.rights == 'admin'  || user.rights == 'owner'  || products.rights.technical)"></div>
```

and also:

```
<div ng-if="::user.rights == 'admin'  || ::user.rights == 'owner'  || ::products.rights.technical"></div>
```

but the condition doesn't seems to work, any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get one-time binding to work for ng-if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275954/get-one-time-binding-to-work-for-ng-if)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? One-time binding has only been available since 1.3

Comment: oups, i'm using angular 1.5.8

Answer (score 1):

Probably, compute `user.rights == 'admin'  || user.rights == 'owner'  || products.rights.technical` at page load and assign it to another scope variable (say `$scope.isOwnerOrAdmin`). And then, use one way binding to bind this variable to ng-if. like: `ng-if="::$scope.isOwnerOrAdmin"`.

Comment: humm you might be right but i've got a lot of differents possibilities, depending on the page i'm not checking for the same right